# ListPointPlot3D with connected points?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

With the command `ListPlot[data,Joined -> True]` I can visually connect adjacent data points in the array with lines.  However, this option appears to be missing in `ListPointPlot3D`?  Is there some manner with which to join with to join (with a line) adjacent three-dimensional points?  There will be a large number of points in my data structure, and I'd really like to keep the standard output format of `ListPointPlot3D`.

Comment: 'Adjacent` can have a rather fuzzy meaning. Are the points on one surface or segregated to some fixed number of surfaces? If so, you can just use `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: @rasher Adjacent just means that the elements in the array are next to one another, e.g. {A,B,C,D,...} would have "A" next to "B", "B" is next to both "A" and "C", and so forth.

Comment: @rasher The problem with ListPlot3D is that I don't want a surface, I just want a "chain" of connected points like this: http://mars.cs.umn.edu/projects/current/VisionAidedINS_MSCKF/office_traject.jpg

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {19, 3}]; 
Show[ListPointPlot3D@pts, Graphics3D@Line@pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Edit:

Something slightly more useful as an example:

```
data = RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.3], {0, 10^2}, 3];
pts = Transpose@data["States"];
Show[ListPointPlot3D@#, Graphics3D@Line@#] &@pts
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very very nice.

Comment: Why not `Graphics3D[{Point@pkt, Line@pkt}]`? Because of `axes` etc?

Comment: @Kuba The OP said _"I'd really like to keep the standard output format of ListPointPlot3D"_, and I think he better way to keep the format of `ListPointPlot3D[]` is by using it :)

Comment: oh, right :) +1 :P

Answer (score 24):

One can use `ListPointPlot3D` and then replace `Point` with `Line`. By this way, the plot can enjoy options of `ListPointPlot3D`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[...]/. Point[a___] :> {Thick, Line[a]}
```

Comment: This is great!! I think your answer is better than Dr. belisarius. belisarius's method join points with black lines. However, if there are groups of curve data, your method gives consistent color in each curve, fantastic!

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same situation, and what worked really well for me was [this answer from a different question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48879/7893).

I'll start off with the random data generated by Dr belisarius:

```
data = RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.3], {0, 10^2}, 3];
pts = Transpose@data["States"];
ListPointPlot3D[pts, ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"]
```

[image]

`pts` is a list of points `{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...}`, we convert this to a list of the form `{{t1,{x1,y1,z1}},{t2,{x2,y2,z2}},...}`:

```
ptsT = Transpose[{Range[1, Length@pts], pts}]
```

We then create a function to interpolate `ptsT`, which we can plot using `ParametericPlot3D`:

```
func = Interpolation[ptsT];
ParametricPlot3D[func[\[Tau]], {\[Tau], 1, Length@pts}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, t}, ColorData["SouthwestColors"][z]]]
```

[image]