# Creating a 3D List Line Plot From Discrete Points

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, interpolation

Given the following Runge-Kutta ODE solver and the graphical output below, how do I get a 3D line plot instead of a 3D point plot? I see that there is no ListLinePlot3D function, so I thought it might be possible to convert the tables of values T1, T2 and T3 into interpolating functions and then use the ParametricPlot3D function to plot the solution in its line form instead of point form. Currently though I'm having a little trouble with the interpolating function + ParametricPlot3D output, as I just get an empty box.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
(*dx/dt=*)f[t_, x_, y_, z_] := σ (y - x);
(*dy/dt=*)g[t_, x_, y_, z_] := x (ρ - z) - y;
(*dz/dt=*)p[t_, x_, y_, z_] := x y - β z;
σ = 10;
ρ = 28;
β = 8/3;
t[0] = 0;
x[0] = 1;
y[0] = 1;
z[0] = 1;
tmax = 2000;
h = 0.01;

Do[
 {t[n] = t[0] + h n,

  k1 = h f[t[n], x[n], y[n], z[n]];
  l1 = h g[t[n], x[n], y[n], z[n]];
  m1 = h p[t[n], x[n], y[n], z[n]];

  k2 = h f[t[n] + h/2, x[n] +  k1/2, y[n] + l1/2, z[n] + m1/2];
  l2 = h g[t[n] + h/2, x[n] +  k1/2, y[n] + l1/2, z[n] + m1/2];
  m2 = h p[t[n] + h/2, x[n] + k1/2, y[n] + l1/2, z[n] + m1/2];

  k3 = h f[t[n] + h/2, x[n] + k2/2, y[n] + l2/2, z[n] + m2/2];
  l3 = h g[t[n] + h/2, x[n] + k2/2, y[n] + l2/2, z[n] + m2/2];
  m3 = h p[t[n] + h/2, x[n] + k2/2, y[n] + l2/2, z[n] +  m2/2];

  k4 = h f[t[n] + h, x[n] + k3, y[n] + l3, z[n] + m3];
  l4 = h g[t[n] + h, x[n] + k3, y[n] + l3, z[n] + m3];
  m4 = h p[t[n] + h, x[n] + k3, y[n] + l3, z[n] + m3];

  x[n + 1] = x[n] + 1/6 (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4);
  y[n + 1] = y[n] + 1/6 (l1 + 2 l2 + 2 l3 + l4);
  z[n + 1] = z[n] + 1/6 (m1 + 2 m2 + 2 m3 + m4);
  }, {n, 0, tmax}]

T1 = Table[{t[i], x[i]}, {i, 0, tmax}];
T2 = Table[{t[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, tmax}];
T3 = Table[{t[i], z[i]}, {i, 0, tmax}];

ListLinePlot[T1]
ListLinePlot[T2]
ListLinePlot[T3]

ListPointPlot3D[Table[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]]

I1 = Interpolation[T1]
I2 = Interpolation[T2]
I3 = Interpolation[T3]
ParametricPlot3D[{I1[t], I2[t], I3[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

What I'm looking to do is essentially get the following Lorenz Attractor point graph into a line graph form:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: `Graphics3D[Line@Table[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]]`

Comment: @Kuba  I didn't see your comment until after I posted my answer.  I had gotten interrupted after I started.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't see any problem :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Like so?

```
 ListPointPlot3D[Table[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}], 
      ViewPoint -> {0, -2, 0}] /. Point -> Line
```

You might be interested in

[link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48626/point-style-in-listpointplot3d)

Answer (score 16):

**Update:** In versions 11+, replace

```
PlotStyle -> {Orange, Specularity[White, 10], (Tube @@ {##}) &}
```

with

```
PlotStyle -> {Orange, Specularity[White, 10], Tube[.5]}
```

when defining `options`.

**Original answer:**

This addresses the `ParametricPlot3D` part of the question.

```
intF = Interpolation[Table[{{t}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}}, {t, 0, tmax}]]; 

options = {PlotStyle -> {Orange, Specularity[White, 10], (Tube @@ {##}) &},
           Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
           PlotRange -> All,  BoxRatios -> 1};

ParametricPlot3D[intF[t], {t, 0, tmax}, Evaluate@options]
```

[image]

Comment: wow ! I would like to see this thing being rotated by a fakir.

Comment: @eldo, yes.. it is much slower to render and to manipulate :)

Comment: That the most important things are done through tubes. Evidence: first, the reproductive organs, the pen and our gun (Georg Christoph Lichtenberg, Sudelbücher, 1770)

Comment: Very beautiful!

Comment: @kglr Very nice, but `Tube` has no effect on version 12. My attempts to fix it failed. Any ideas?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, updated with a variant that should work in versions 11+.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to get a `Line`:

```
Graphics3D @ Line @ Table[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

or, with style,

```
Graphics3D[
 {ColorData[1][1], Thickness[Medium], 
  Line[Table[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]]},
 Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For fun, a variation on @eldo's that handles both a colored plot and a regular one:

```
ListPointPlot3D[Table[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"] /.
  {l : {{_RGBColor, _Point} ..} :>
    ({Thickness[Medium],
      Transpose[l] /. {c_, p_} :> Line[First /@ p, VertexColors -> c]}),
  Point[p_] :> {Thickness[Medium], Line[p]}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: very nice ! If the underlying formula would be simpler you could even color it by curvature, speed or acceleration. Don't know how to do this with this beast.

Comment: @eldo Thanks! One could use the differential equations to write the derivatives (of any order) in terms of the coordinates.