# Runge-Kutta 2nd Order ODE Solver

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

Suppose I have a 2nd order ODE of the form `y''(t) = 1/y` with `y(0) = 0` and `y'(0) = 10`, and want to solve it using a Runge-Kutta solver. I've read that we need to convert the 2nd order ODE into two 1st order ODEs, but I'm having trouble doing that at the moment and am hoping someone here might be able to help. This is my code thus far:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
(*dy/dt=*)f[t_, y_] := 1/y;
(*d^2y/dt^2=*)g[t_, y_, yd_] :=???;
t[0] = 0;
y[0] = 0;
yd[0] = 10;
tmax = 1000;
h = 0.01;

Do[
 {t[n] = t[0] + h n,

  k1 = h f[t[n], y[n], yd[n]];
  l1 = h g[t[n], y[n], yd[n]];

  k2 = h f[t[n] + h/2, y[n] +  k1/2, yd[n] + l1/2];
  l2 = h g[t[n] + h/2, y[n] +  k1/2, yd[n] + l1/2];

  k3 = h f[t[n] + h/2, y[n] + k2/2, yd[n] + l2/2];
  l3 = h g[t[n] + h/2, y[n] + k2/2, yd[n] + l2/2];

  k4 = h f[t[n] + h, y[n] + k3, yd[n] + l3];
  l4 = h g[t[n] + h, y[n] + k3, yd[n] + l3];

  y[n + 1] = y[n] + 1/6 (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4);
  yd[n + 1] = yd[n] + 1/6 (l1 + 2 l2 + 2 l3 + l4);

  }, {n, 0, tmax}]
```

As you can see by the question marks for the function `g[t_,y_,yd_]`, I don't know how I can set it in such a way that `y''(t) = 1/y`. Do I feed the results of `y[n+1]` into `g` when running the algorithm? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe related: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48875/creating-a-3d-list-line-plot-from-discrete-points/48879#48879)

Comment: That's the question I asked yesterday :) I want to move on from a plain system of 1st order ODEs to a 2nd order ODE using a system of equations.

Comment: oops, shame over me :)

Comment: Have a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html

Comment: Thanks Sascha, but unfortunately that doesn't show explicitly how to convert a 2nd order ODE to two 1st order ODEs using RK4. It seems to give more of an overview of possible solvers used by NDSolve.

Comment: As far as I am concerned the type of solver (e.g. Runge Kutta, explicit Euler,...) doesn't have anything to do with rewriting an ODE of order n as n individual first order ODEs

Comment: I'm not necessarily trying to find out how to numerically solve a 2nd order ODE using RK4 only, but since I have the algorithm at hand and RK4 is very common, I chose to try and solve it using this solver. I know how to convert 2nd order ODEs to systems of 1st order ODEs and solve them on paper, but doing it numerically in Mathematica is proving tricky as I do know have enough experience as I would like in using the language. Your link doesn't seem to give any algorithms for solving 2nd order ODEs, it only seems to give variable coefficients for different methods.

Comment: The link I provided shows you how to numerically solve differential equations in Mathematica. You don't have to implement your own algorithm - Mathematica comes with tones of algorithms for almost everything. You don't even have to tell Mathematica which algorithm to use as it automatically chooses one if non is explicitly given.

Comment: I've been using NDSolve extensively for the past year, but I always like knowing how things work, so this post was my attempt at figuring out how numerical ODE solving works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the functions like this

```
(*dy/dt=*)f[t_, y_, yd_] := yd;
(*d^2y/dt^2=*)g[t_, y_, yd_] := 1/y;
t[0] = 0;
y[0] = 1;
yd[0] = 10;
tmax = 1000;
h = 0.01;
Do[{t[n] = t[0] + h n, k1 = h f[t[n], y[n], yd[n]];
  l1 = h g[t[n], y[n], yd[n]];
  k2 = h f[t[n] + h/2, y[n] + k1/2, yd[n] + l1/2];
  l2 = h g[t[n] + h/2, y[n] + k1/2, yd[n] + l1/2];
  k3 = h f[t[n] + h/2, y[n] + k2/2, yd[n] + l2/2];
  l3 = h g[t[n] + h/2, y[n] + k2/2, yd[n] + l2/2];
  k4 = h f[t[n] + h, y[n] + k3, yd[n] + l3];
  l4 = h g[t[n] + h, y[n] + k3, yd[n] + l3];
  y[n + 1] = y[n] + 1/6 (k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4);
  yd[n + 1] = yd[n] + 1/6 (l1 + 2 l2 + 2 l3 + l4);}, {n, 0, tmax}]
```

The function *f* is the derivative of *y* and therefore equal to *yd*. The function *g* is the derivative of *yd* which means it is the second derivative of the function you are looking for. Here you can specify the right hand side of the equation *y''=1/y*.

Also, you shouldn't specify y(0) = 0 in your initial conditions, because then 1/y is not defined.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to do the trick. I've also tried setting `f[t_, y_, yd_] := y;` and that didn't work either.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the complete code. This works fine when I run it. Note that you have to set `y[0]=1;`.

Comment: If you try `g[t_, y_, yd_] := -y` (Hooke's Law) and then plot the output using `Soln1 = Table[{t[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, tmax}];`, `Soln2 = Table[{t[i], yd[i]}, {i, 0, tmax}];`
`ListLinePlot[Soln1]`, and `ListLinePlot[Soln2]` and compare this to the results from NDSolve using `y'[t] == -y[t]` and `y''[t] == -y[t]` you'll see that something is slightly awry.

Comment: Apologies! Having had a closer look, I see that you are in fact correct. Thank you Holger, I appreciate your help.