# How can I can plot a stochastic process?

Tags: plotting, stochastic-calculus

How I can plot the following stochastic process using mathmatica

[image: Stochastic process]

Comment: Just showing us a picture of the plot is not enough information to answer your question. Show us the code that generates the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First generate a collection of random processes (e.g., 100 Wiener Processes):

```
process = RandomFunction[
  WienerProcess[.3, .5],
  {0, 1, 0.01},
  100 (*creates an ensemble of 100 processes*)]
```

Directly plotting these overlaps them (which is not what you want):```

```
ListLinePlot[process]
```

[image: ListLinePlot output]

To get them separated, you need to do a bit of preprocessing.  I turn these into normal lists and prepend an index value to each element in the list, before sending it to ListPointPlot3D:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Table[
  Prepend[i] /@ process["Paths"][[i]],
  {i, 100}]
 ]
```

[image: ListPointPlot3D output]

Comment: But how I can plot them as a line  not point? Could you do that?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48875/creating-a-3d-list-line-plot-from-discrete-points