# Wrong height of vertical lines in a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want stack some vertical lines around a circle. I have used tips on [ListPointPlot3D with connected points?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41013/listpointplot3d-with-connected-points)

Here is my code

`pts = Table[ With[{theta = pipi},  Table[{Cos[theta], Sin [theta], z}, {z, 0, 7, 0.1}]], {pipi, 0,  2 Pi, Pi/6}];`

`ptsT[k_] := Transpose[{Range[1, Length@pts[[k]]], pts[[k]]}];  func[k_] := Interpolation[ptsT[k]];`

`ploplo[k_] :=  With[{func = Interpolation[ptsT[k]]},  ParametricPlot3D[func[\[Tau]], {\[Tau], 1, Length@pts},  ColorFunction ->  Function[{x, y, z, t}, ColorData["SouthwestColors"][z]]]]`

`Show[Table[ploplo[k], {k, 1, Length@pts}],  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 7}}]`

The 3D plot renders the lines shorter, they are supposed to have 7 units and they are way shorter.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the domain of `ParametricPlot3D` in `ploplo`. In your case, `Length@pts` is `13`, not `71` (= `Length@ptsT[k]`).

You can fix it as, for example:

```
ploplo[k_] := With[{func = Interpolation[ptsT[k]]},
  ParametricPlot3D[
    func[\[Tau]],
    {\[Tau], 1, Max[func["Domain"]]},
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, ColorData["SouthwestColors"][z]]
  ]
]
```

Comment: That was really useful, love this forum