# Color a 3D line plot of list of lists

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

Assume a list of lists of length n of the kind:

```
t = {{x1, y1, z1, p1},{x2, y2, z2, p2},...,{xn, yn, zn, pn}}.
```

1. I'd like to make a `ListLinePlot3D` of the list given by `t[[All,{1,2,3}]]`. I'm working with Mathematica 11.0, so the function `ListLinePlot3D` is not available. I've failed to adapt my problem to what is recommended [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41013/listpointplot3d-with-connected-points). Maybe the function `ParametricPlot3D` may do the job as well, but I can't figure it out.
2. The resulting line should be colored using the values `p1, p2,...,pn` as arguments for the `ColorFunction`. These values range from `0` to `0.86`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the Mathematica code that you have tried out so far. Also to make this question concrete, include `t` (list of points).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[123];

t = RandomReal[1, {10, 4}];

minmax = MinMax[t[[All, 4]]];

color[x_] := ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[x, minmax]]

Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[2],
  Line[{Most@#[[1]], Most@#[[2]]},
     VertexColors ->
      {color@Last@#[[1]],
       color@Last@#[[2]]}] & /@
   Partition[t, 2, 1],
  AbsolutePointSize[4],
  {color[Last@#], Point[Most@#]} & /@ t},
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[123]
xyzp = RandomReal[1, {10, 4}];
```

**Graphics3D**

Two additional variations using `Graphics3D` + `VertexColors`:

```
plt1 = Graphics3D[{Thick, PointSize[Large],
    #[xyzp[[All, ;; 3]], VertexColors -> 
      (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[xyzp[[All, 4]]])]& /@ {Line, Point}}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium];

plt2 = Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[xyzp[[All, ;; 3]],
    {Thick, PointSize[Large],
     #[Range @ Length @ xyzp, VertexColors -> Automatic]& /@ {Line, Point}}, 
    VertexColors -> (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[xyzp[[All, -1]]])], 
    ImageSize -> Medium];

Row[{plt1, plt2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**ParametricPlot3D**

Use `BSplineFunction` to get spline interpolations of the first three coordinates to define a custom `ColorFunction` using spline interpolation of the last coordinates, and use the options `MeshFunctions` + `Mesh` + `Method` to add styled points:

```
bSF = BSplineFunction[xyzp[[All, ;; 3]], SplineDegree -> 1];

cF = ColorData["Rainbow"][BSplineFunction[Rescale@xyzp[[All, 4]], SplineDegree -> 1]@#] &

ParametricPlot3D[bSF[t], {t, 0, 1},
 ColorFunction -> (cF@ # 4 &), 
 MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{#, Directive[PointSize[Large], cF@#]} & /@ Subdivide[Length@ xyzp -1]}, 
 Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**ListLinePlot3D**

For those with version 12.3+, a way to use [`ListLinePlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot3D.html) with a custom `ColorFunction`:

```
iF = Interpolation[Thread[{xyzp[[All, ;; 3]], Rescale[xyzp[[All, 4]]]}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Automatic, "WarningMessage" -> False}];

cFLLP = ColorData["Rainbow"]@iF[#, #2, #3] &;

ListLinePlot3D[xyzp[[All, ;; 3]], 
  ColorFunction -> cFLLP, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  Ticks -> None, BoxRatios -> 1, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Large}] /. 
 Point[x_, _] :> Point[x, VertexColors -> (cFLLP @@ x)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have ListLinePlot3D, you can still use Line together with Graphics:

```
dat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 3}];
Graphics3D[{Line[dat]}]
```

[image]